# AngularJS date filter in range by two inputs

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I want to display data in range of `date` by two inputs of `date`. (AngularJS date filter in range by two inputs)

#### Here is my code

```
 var app = angular.module('app',[]).controller('ctrl1', function($scope){
            $scope.record = [
                 {uniqueID : 'pp-12', Name : 'Jim', status : 'Approved', Date:'05/01/2015' },
                 {uniqueID : 'pp-11', Name : 'Jim', status : 'Canceled', Date:'05/02/2015' },
                 {uniqueID : 'pp-45', Name : 'Nick', status : 'Pending', Date:'05/03/2015' },
                 {uniqueID : 'pp-32', Name : 'Thomas', status : 'Canceled', Date:'05/04/2015' },
                 {uniqueID : 'pp-01', Name : 'Thomas', status : 'Pending', Date:'05/05/2015' },
                 {uniqueID : 'pp-09', Name : 'Nick', status : 'Approved', Date:'05/06/2015' },
                 {uniqueID : 'pp-23', Name : 'Lina', status : 'Requested', Date:'05/07/2015'},
                 {uniqueID : 'pp-39', Name : 'Jim', status : 'Pending', Date:'05/08/2015' }
            ];
         });

  <input type="text" class="form-control" name="to" ng-model="to">
  <input type="text" class="form-control" name="from" ng-model="from"> 
        <table border="1">
            <thead>
            <tr>
                <td>Unique ID</td>
                <td>Name</td>
                <td>Status</td>
                <td>Date</td>
            </tr>
            </thead>

            <tbody>
            <tr ng-repeat="data in  record">
                <td> {{data.uniqueID}}</td>
                <td> {{data.Name}}</td>
                <td> {{data.status}}</td>
                <td> {{data.Date}}</td>
            </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
```

Thanks is advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define a [custom filter](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/filter#creating-custom-filters) for that purpose that filters the record array and returns an array with all entries between the given dates:

```
.filter('dateRange', function() {
    return function(records, from, to) {
        return records.filter(function(record) {
            return record.Date >= from && record.Date <= to;
        });
    }
})

<tr ng-repeat="data in  record | dateRange : from : to">
```

**Plunker**: http://plnkr.co/edit/smpnaDtY3vPmdCuw20bT?p=preview

---

PS: you should add a `track by record.uniqueID` to the `ng-repeat`.

Comment: Hi thank you for your response in this example list data is not showing until i choose date.

Comment: That's right, depending on what you wan't to do if `from` or `to` (or both) are not defined, you can simply adjust the line `return record.Date >= from && record.Date <= to;` accordingly. You should also think about invalid user inputs.

Comment: I created one pen http://codepen.io/anujsphinx/pen/OpJrOm  . Why is it not working ?

Comment: Any idea @Numyx :(

Comment: Looks like your `to` value is just less than your `from` value, http://codepen.io/anon/pen/WpbvVV

Answer (score 1):

If you want all the records if user has not enter the from and to dates then change you filter to this:

```
.filter('dateRange', function() {
    return function(records, from, to) {
        return records.filter(function(record) {
            if(from && to)
                return record.Date >= from && record.Date <= to;
            else
                return record.Date;
        });
    }
})
```